# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) again

Tags: python

I have this error and I am stuck here. Can someone help, please?

```
for row, is_corrupt in ([{'a': 'b'}], True):
    print(row)
    print(is_corrupt)
```

I am getting the error :

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

PS:- I am getting `([{'a': 'b'}], True)` froma generator method.

Comment: What are you expected values for `row` and `is_corrupt` per iteration?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What does {'a':'b'} mean?

Comment: `for ... in ...` already iterates over a collection, in this case the outermost tuple. It then tries to destructure each item. So it will first try to destructure `[{'a': 'b'}]` into two items, then `True` into two items. This should make the failure obvious. If you want to simply destructure `([{'a': 'b'}], True)` , you can simply do away with the iteration and use assignment instead: `row, is_corrupt = ([{'a': 'b'}], True)`

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating over a tuple of two items:

```
[{'a': 'b'}]
True
```

In neither case do you have two items that can be unpacked into two variables.

What you seem to want to do is simply:

```
row, is_corrupt = ([{'a': 'b'}], True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
for row, is_corrupt in [([{'a': 'b'}], True)]:
    print(row)
    print(is_corrupt)
```